# How to get name of sdcard in Android?

Tags: android, android-sdcard

I know there is a way to do because I remember doing it a long time ago.

I'm looking to retrieve the string name of the sdcard currently mounted in android, as it shows up in Finder/Windows Explorer.

Any insights?

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Under Settings->Storage there should be an option for "Mount SD card". Tapping on that menu item should show you all the details about the card.